# Google Drive with proxy authentication

Tags: proxy, google-drive

I'm unable to connect the [Google Drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive) application to the Internet. I'm quite sure it's because of the proxy authentication. How can I fix this problem?

Windows 7 64 bit, proxy with authentication.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm behind a proxy at work which requires proxy authentication, and wouldn't work with [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29). So I followed the instructions in *[Allow Dropbox to authenticate with an NTLM proxy server](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/TipsAndTricks/AllowDropboxtoauthenticatewithanNTLMproxyserver)* to setup Dropbox with Cntlm (a kind of local machine proxy server). Happily you can make Google Drive use the same localhost proxy to connect to the Internet by simply changing your browser settings.

In Internet Explorer: Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections Tab -> LAN settings button.

Set the proxy server address to localhost and the port to whatever you configured Cntlm to use (3128 in my case).

Press OK to the settings and restart Google Drive. So long as your corporate firewall isn't blocking the actual web addresses for Google Drive you should now be OK, and you should still be able to browse.

Comment: Thx for this. Im having problems with determining the 'Domain' field in the configuration file. Any idea whats supposed to go there?

Comment: My work PC is on a domain group. You can probably work yours out by browsing your network (In windows 7 that's the "Network" icon you can see when open explorer), and changing the resulting window to "Show Details". There is a column called "Workgroup" the contents of which is probably your domain. It is mine.

Comment: It worked with the instructions provided by DraxReaper. I have a Windows Domain environment. Thanks!

Comment: Well I havent tried this yet, but I guess this should work. @ditzah tried it and says it worked, so I think I should accept this. If this worked for anyone else, then do comment here.

Comment: Broken link resource. This is the archive site for the link provided in this answer as solution: https://web.archive.org/web/20150517204543/http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/allow-dropbox-to-authenticate-with-a-ntlm-proxy-server

Answer (score 3):

In fact, Google says: "Google Drive for Mac/PC supports all unauthenticated proxies that are configured by the operating system."

I guess this is the same that "Google Drive for Mac/PC doesn't support authenticated proxies".

Answer (score 1):

Google has information on what firewall rules to add, but to be honest, compared to Dropbox's simple proxy settings, this one is a pain.

https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2589954&topic=14951&ctx=topic

> **Google Drive for your PC/Mac**
>
> www.google.com:443/HTTPS
>   accounts.google.com:443/HTTPS
>   clients3.google.com:443/HTTPS
>   talk.google.com:5222/XMPP
>   drive.google.com:443/HTTPS
>   www.googleapis.com:443/HTTPS
>   ssl.gstatic.com:443/HTTPS
>   *.docs.google.com:443/HTTPS
>   *.drive.google.com:443/HTTPS
>   *.googleusercontent.com:443/HTTPS
>
> **Google Drive for the web**
>
> s.ytimg.com:443/HTTPS
>   video.google.com:443/HTTPS
>   lh3.google.com:443/HTTPS
>   lh4.google.com:443/HTTPS
>   lh5.google.com:443/HTTPS
>   lh6.google.com:443/HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

I work in a call center (in IT). We apply a default policy on our proxy so that our callers cannot access the internet (except for select sites) when they are working (they can during their breaks).

As a result anyone in the back office that wants to use the internet for http/s must authenticate with the proxy - which is of cause not supported by Google Drive.

My workaround was to set workstations that need access to Google Drive to bypass the proxy for  google.com, which is now allowed through the proxy without authentication.

I can't see that there is an option for people who have no option but to authenticate with a proxy though.

Answer (score 0):

A crude workaround for online access:

If it's just the file listing that is blocked by the proxy and not the files themselves (like in my company), the following page will list your Google Drive files and allow you to open them:

> https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxGicVpPA1dxcy_pvr32aFKDqY7fow86g32u6173AhGH8Gm-UM/exec

This is a simple Google app script. It will ask for authorization. You can review the code by replacing `exec` with `edit` in the URL:

> https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxGicVpPA1dxcy_pvr32aFKDqY7fow86g32u6173AhGH8Gm-UM/edit

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just add two keys at your registry. Navigate to the key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

and add String values called `ProxyPass` and `ProxyUser`. Fill them with yourProxyPassword and yourProxyUsername and be happy!

If you auth at proxy under domain user, use `domainName\username` for `ProxyUser` key.

Google Drive automatically detects proxy settings.

Comment: Why would you do this by hand instead of using the IE GUI to do it?

Comment: Ramhound: It is not possible to enter proxy user and password in IE GUI.

Comment: Did not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to disable proxy in Internet Explorer and instead to use a proxifier that supports HTTP proxies. You will need to know the network address of the proxy server.

I will use [Proxycap](http://www.proxycap.com) in this example. It is easy to configure, and has a very nice option: "Use integrated Windows authentication".

Here are the step-by-step instructions:
1. In Proxycap follow these steps:
- Configuration -> Proxies
- Add HTTP proxy (set Type to HTTP)
- Add HTTPS proxy (same settings as for HTTP proxy, but Type=HTTPS)
- Configuration -> Rules
- Add "Force direct connection" rule for your LAN IP range, such as 192.168.0.0/24
- Add rule: action="redirect", proxy=[HTTP_PROXY], all programs, port=80
- Add rule: action="redirect" proxy=[HTTPS_PROXY], all programs, port=443
- Close the Configuration box by clicking OK.
2. In Internet Explorer follow these steps:
- Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections tab -> LAN settings button
- Uncheck all checkboxes